# help in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-modeling

I am having a question in regression analysis in JMP or any other tool.

I have one dependent variable $y$ and $2$ independent variables $x_1$ and $x_2$.

For example:

time $= y  -$ per row time ( total time divided by total rows, $x_2$).

new rows added to $db = x_1$.

total rows in $db = x_2$

total time $= t$  for a database query

observed time $y$ (per row) $=$ total time $t /$ total rows $x_2$

$x_1$ is number of new rows added to database.

As you can see, data base rows ($x_2$) increase as new rows are added ($x_1$) . So per row time ($y$) decreases when number of rows added to $db$ are more.

sample data :
$$
\begin{matrix}
y & x_1 & x_2 \\
0.000465116 & 0 & 86 \\
0.000659091 & 1 & 44 \\
0.000597561 & 2 & 82 \\
0.000635294 & 2 & 85 \\
0.00053271 & 2 & 107 \\
0.000590909 & 2 & 110 \\
0.0005 & 2 & 244 \\
0.000577075 & 2 & 253 \\
0.000685714 & 3 & 35 \\
0.000947368 & 3 & 38 \\
0.000717949 & 3 & 39 \\
0.000755556 & 3 & 45 \\
0.000574468 & 3 & 47 \\
0.000716981 & 3 & 53
\end{matrix}
$$

Can anyone suggest how I should approach this ?

I am getting $R^2$ as $50\%$ when I only try to model $y$ and $x_1 \to$ meaning $50\%$ of my data is correct using this linear fit.

Should I be modeling, per row time ($y$) with number of rows added ? Its a bit confusing I know. I would be happy to clear the details if anyone require more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you speak about multilinear regression, start using $y=a+b x1+c x2$. Come back with your results and we could continue the discussion.

By the way, you have a very surprizing way for the interpretation of $R^2$

Comment: I was also puzzled by the OPs use of $R^{2}$.

Comment: as far as i know from this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination determines, how good is the fit. (r^2 = 1 means the chosen model correctly fits the data.

Comment: $R^2=1$ means that the model is perfect. When, in physics, I have an $R^2=0.98$, I am not happy at all. Take points along a circle (not centered at the origin) and perform a linear regression. You would be surprized ! Did you perform the regression I suggested (you can use Excel) ?

Comment: yes, when i try to fit my data in this : y=a(x)^b, I get this as my model: y = 5.953990281·10-4 ( x )^(0.04015083873) with an RSS of rss = 1.335389025·10^-6. this RSS value seems to be less. but data (y) is of order 10^-3. (0.0004..)

Comment: @user24 04319. The title of your post is $"help$ $in$ $multiple$ $linear$ $regression"$. Do you think that what you tried corresponds to what you asked ? By the way, all your numbers are less than 0.001 and you have 14 data points; so, a RSS of 10^(-6) is HUGE.

Comment: the data is about 200 points. i just posted a snippet. I wanted to help establish a relationship between y and x considering what i explained for time (y) and number of rows (x1) or total rows(x2) ... without. for example, for x1 = 2, we can see that x2 value changes and hence time y = total rows / total time changes too. (because y is per row time)

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

Sequence of $m=14$ points:
$$
\left\{ 
 x_{k}, y_{k}, z_{k}
\right\}_{k=1}^{m}
$$

**Model**

A plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$:
$$
 z(x,y) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2}
$$

**Linear system**

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} a &= z \\
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1 & 0 & 86 \\
 1 & 1 & 44 \\
 1 & 2 & 82 \\
 1 & 2 & 85 \\
 1 & 2 & 107 \\
 1 & 2 & 110 \\
 1 & 2 & 244 \\
 1 & 2 & 253 \\
 1 & 3 & 35 \\
 1 & 3 & 38 \\
 1 & 3 & 39 \\
 1 & 3 & 45 \\
 1 & 3 & 47 \\
 1 & 3 & 53 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% a
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 a_{0} \\ a_{1}  \\ a_{2}
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
% z
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 0.000465116 \\ 0.000659091 \\ 0.000597561 \\ 0.000635294 \\ 0.00053271 \\ 0.000590909 \\ 0.0005 \\ 0.000577075 \\ 0.000685714 \\ 0.000947368 \\ 0.000717949 \\ 0.000755556 \\ 0.000574468 \\ 0.000716981
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**Normal equations**

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} a &= \mathbf{A}^{*} z \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 14 & 31 & 1268 \\
 31 & 79 & 2577 \\
 1268 & 2577 & 181608 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% a
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 a_{0} \\ a_{1}  \\ a_{2}
\end{array}
\right]
% 
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0.00895579 \\ 0.0207203 \\ 0.749
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**Normal equations solution**

$$
\begin{align}
%
   a &= \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} z \\
%
&=
%
\frac{1}{8935490}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 7706103 & -2362212 & -20285 \\
 -2362212 & 934688 & 3230 \\
 -20285 & 3230 & 145 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 0.00895579 \\ 0.0207203 \\ 0.749
\end{array}
\right] \\[5pt]
%
& =
%
\left[
\begin{array}{l}
 \phantom{-}0.000545584 \\ \phantom{-}0.0000705953 \\ -0.000000686778 
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$